# When adding more than one "or" condition to an InfoPath rule for formatting , the rule stops working

Tags: infopath

If I just leave the first condition by itself , it works just fine.
If I add a second or more to the OR condition the rules stops working.
The idea is if anyone but one of these users are viewing this form then hide an area.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

UPDATED PICTURE

Comment: Instead of `does not contain` won't it be `not equals`?.. This is not the answer to your question.. just a suggestion

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be "does not equal" for the image I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the issue at hand is that the section is always being hidden for user1/2/3 when using multiple conditions, I believe you just need to use AND operators instead of OR operators for this.

InfoPath uses the formatting rule to hide something when the condition is TRUE. Thus, if you want your section to be visible whenever CurrentUser = user1/2/3, then your condition needs to be FALSE.  Kind of annoying, as it's generally more logical to think about how you make something TRUE.

If we look at your picture as conditions A, B, and C, then if we only have condition A and CurrentUser = "user1", then A = FALSE and thus the rule doesn't run and the section remains visible.

Now if we have A OR B, A = FALSE still, but B = TRUE (CurrentUser = user1 != "user2"), thus A OR B = TRUE OR FALSE > TRUE and your rule runs, hiding the section, which isn't what you want to have happen.

Thus for OR statements, you'd require all conditions to be FALSE in order to see the section.  Instead, you'd want to use AND, so it only requires one to be true; A AND B = TRUE AND FALSE > FALSE, thus InfoPath shows the section.

And to show it won't break the other way, if CurrentUser = "user9", then A AND B = TRUE AND TRUE > True, thus InfoPath hides the section.

Comment: Wow Jordan that is very concise and generous of you. But WTF to InfoPath.. so what I forgot to show in the picture above is I that I had check-boxed "hide the section" hoping that it would translate to the section would only show for those three users. "Thus for OR statements, you'd require all conditions to be FALSE in order to see the section. Instead, you'd want to use AND, so it only requires one to be true; A AND B = TRUE AND FALSE>FALSE, thus InfoPath shows the section.." Really? It's misleading to think that it means A, B & C must b all "affirmative" 2 use AND when it really means just1

Comment: So in essence I would have it to say if CurrentUser !=1 AND CurrentUser !=2 AND CurrentUser !=3 ...then check the hide the section THEN it will do what I had intended which is just to show that section for those 3 users?
That it doesn't require all three to be "affirmative" despite  that it uses AND? And that it only requires one to be true even if it's the last one in order? Is that correct Jordan? If so that is maddening! Was maddening. I suppose the thought behind that was "conjugating three separate sentences" in an "envelope" as opposed to turning all three into a "singular paragraph"?

Comment: The easiest way I've found to think about it is that in InfoPath, you're selecting the "Hide this section" if the condition is TRUE, thus, you're essentially wrapping your whole condition in a NOT() operator of how you'd normally think about it.  In your example, you'd normally think "If user = 1 OR 2 OR 3 > TRUE > show section".  But since InfoPath only gives you the option to hide it, you can think of it as NOT(user = 1 OR 2 OR 3) which would translate to user = 1 AND 2 AND 3 > FALSE.  Hopefully that makes sense :P

Comment: And sorry, since I forgot to actually answer your last question, regarding how it should be setup - Yes, that should make it work the way you want.  Hopefully my previous comment helps explain the reason for why it works that way.  Also, my last translation was incorrect, forgot to negate the "=".  It should be: NOT(user = 1 OR 2 OR 3) becomes user != 1 AND 2 AND 3.

Comment: Jordan you rock. Thank you. Wishing you awesome good karma. : )