# Not sure how to add multiple conditions to formatting rule in Infopath 2013

Tags: infopath

I'm creating a Sharepoint site for folks in my company to submit their documents to our legal team for review.  I've created an Infopath form tied to a list but some of the questions on the form aren't applicable to certain types of documents. In an effort to keep things as simple as possible for my users, I've added a section that contains just those questions and I want it to show only when the user selects a specific document type.  I've gotten this function to work using one condition on other questions on the form, but can't figure out a way to get it to work for multiple conditions.

This is the section I want to show...

[image]

...when these specific document types are selected from the 'Document Type' list above (this may expand to others if I can get this dang thing to work).

[image]

I read another [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192683/when-adding-more-than-one-or-condition-to-an-infopath-rule-for-formatting-th/192715) on this site where the user was having the exact same issue, but for some reason the same principles didn't apply to my situation.

This is how I'm setting up my conditional formatting -- neither 'and' or 'or' seem to be working.

[image]

Any help would be so appreciated!  I'm getting quite a headache from banging my head against my desk. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two things: First, "not equal to" is more confusing to work with. All of your conditions should be set to "and". If it's set to "or", and the user picks bulletin, then it's not "application tip", and so the condition yields true and your section is hidden.

Second, InfoPath rule conditions are case sensitive, so adjust your conditions to be "**B**ulletin", etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  I still had to set the rule to 'not equal to' but using the correct case and the word 'and' made it function as I wanted.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ErinHanlon Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you! also take a [tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) to now how can you accept and upvote the helpful answer